# Boolean, Flatnonzero, Selecting a certain range in numpy in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have a data file in .txt that consists of 2 columns. The first one is my x values and the second column contains my y values.

What I am trying to do is quite simple. I want to identify where my x values are =>1700 and <=1735 so that I can get the repective y values within that x range. At the end I want to get the sum of those y values.

The following is the code I wrote.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('NI2_2.txt')
x_all= data[:,0]
y_all= data[:,1]
x_selected= np.flatnonzero(np.logical_and(x_all<=1700),(x_all=>1735))
y_selected= y_all[x_selected]
y_final= np.sum(y_selected)
```

I get an error message for my x_selected, saying that the syntax is not correct. Does someone see what is wrong with it?

Thanks!
Cece

Answer (score 1):

Try using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
y_selected = y_all[np.where((x_all >= 1700) & (x_all <= 1735))]
y_final = np.sum(y_selected)
```

EDIT:
Also you cannot write `=>` in python. Use `>=`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be only because the comparison operand is >= and not => but i can't try any further, sorry.